# How to give range in lookhead using regex e.g ^(?=(.*[a-z]){1,3})(?=.*[0-9]).{2,5}$

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

```
Question-
1]String length is 2 to 5 
2]String contains at least 1 char and maximum 3 char
3]Atleast one number
```

I want do using lookhead. 
What i tried but not working
^(?=(.*[a-z]){1,3})(?=.*[0-9]).{2,5}$

Comment: ^(?=(.*[a-z]){1,3})(?=.*[0-9]).{2,5}$

Comment: Sorry, that was me being practically blind... ;-)

Comment: Might you have an example input set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a positive lookahead to assert that the length of the string is 2-5 characters and that there is at least 1 digit and 1 character `[a-z]`. To make sure that there is a maximum of 3 characters to can use a negative lookahead to assert that you don't match a character 4 times.

`^(?=[a-z0-9]{2,5}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?!(?:.*[a-z]){4})[a-z0-9]+$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FBkkIk/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the line
- `(?=[a-z0-9]{2,5}$` Positive lookahead to assert 2 -5 characters
- `(?=.*[a-z])` Positive lookahead to assert 1 character
- `(?=.*[0-9])` Positive lookahead to assert 1 digit
- `(?!(?:.*[a-z]){4})` Negative lookahead to not match a character 4 times
- `[a-z0-9]+$` Match one or more times a character or a digit until the end of the string

[Demo](http://rextester.com/QCBG54339)

Comment: I have tried this and  it working fine for ^(?=[0-9]{2,4}$)
but when we tried this its not working ^(?=[0-9]{1,4}$)(?=[a-z]{1,3}$).{5}$

I want understand why its working or why not working

Comment: Your requirements are a string length 2-5, minimum 1 char and max 3 chars and at least 1 digit. In that case `^(?=[0-9]{2,4}$)` does not work because that asserts that there should be 2 -4 consecitive digits from the start of the string until the end if the string. That will not meet the requirement of 2 -5 length because that maximum is 4 and there is no character in that assertion. If the first lookahead was true, the the second one `(?=[a-z]{1,3}$)` can not match because there will not be a character `[a-z]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below regex

`(?=([\\w\\W]{2,5}$))(?=(.*([0-9]){1,}.*))^[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z](?!(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){3})`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "(?=([\\w\\W]{2,5}$))(?=(.*([0-9]){1,}.*))^[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z](?!(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){3}).*";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("AB2").find()); // output true
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("AB2C").find()); // output true
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and  it working fine for ^(?=[0-9]{2,4}$)
but when we tried this its not working ^(?=[0-9]{1,4}$)(?=[a-z]{1,3}$).{5}$

I want understand why its working or why not working

Comment: `(?=[a-z]{1,3}$)` or `(?=[0-9]{1,4}$)` will look for consecutive characters/digits. i.e if you have consecutive characters(a-z) from length 1 to 3, then `(?=[a-z]{1,3}$)` should return true. Same is the case for number

Comment: If you have non-consecutive characters, you can try `^([^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){1,3}[^A-Za-z]*$`. It first checkes if there are any non-character, followed by characters and then again non-character. Hope this helps